# Linq query to count and group items by date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of `Orders` which are pulled from EF.  Each `Order` has an order date:

```
public class Order {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to run a query to return the number of orders for each day in a certain date range.   The query method should look something like:

```
public class ICollection<OrderDateSummary> GetOrderTotalsForDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {

      var orderDateSummary = Set.SelectMany(u => u.Orders) // ..... grouping/totalling here?!

      return orderDateSummary;
}
```

For info, `Set` is actually part of a repository which returns a User aggregate root, so the type of `Set` is `DbSet<User>` The bit I am stuck on is grouping and totalling the `Orders` queryable from the `SelectMany` method.

The OrderDateSummary class looks like:

```
public OrderDateSummary {
      DateTime Date { get; set; }
      int Total { get; set; }
}
```

So, the output for a start date of 01/01/2016 and an end date of 03/01/2016 would look something like:

```
Date          Total
===================
01/01/2016       10
02/01/2016        2
03/01/2016        0
04/01/2016       12
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Can´t see a question nor any error that may occur.

Comment: var x =orderDateSummary = Set.SelectMany(u => u.Orders).where(x=>x.startdate>=sdate && x.Enddate<=edate).select(x=>x.total)

Comment: Do you also need to have zero-rows `03/01/2016 - 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you need to generate all dates in range from `start` to `end`. Then calculate total number of orders on each date.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2016, 1, 4);
Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 + (end - start).Days)
    .Select(x => start.AddDays(x))
    .GroupJoin(Set.SelectMany(u => u.Orders),
        dt => dt, o => o.Date.Date,
        (dt, orders) => new OrderDateSummary { Date = dt, Total = orders.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Check out [working example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/iP494S).

Comment: This looks like the best solution as it should add in zero for any days that don't have an order.  However, when I used the query, it returned zero count total for all days?

Comment: @Graham, check out edit. Changed `o => o.Date` -> `o => o.Date.Date`. I thought you've had order dates without time, but if you say that you get zeros it might be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
var startDate = new DateTime (2016, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime (2016, 1, 4);

Set.SelectMany(u => u.Orders).
    Where (order => startDate <= order.Date && order.Date <= endDate) // If filter needed
    GroupBy (order => order.Date, (date, values) =>
        new OrderDateSummary () {
            Date = date,
            Total = values.Count ()
        }).
    OrderBy (summary => summary.Date).
    ToList ();
```

Just you should mark your `OrderDateSummary` with `class` or `struct` and make those properties `public` or add constructor.

And you have a date 04/01/2016 in expected result, so, I guess, your end time is 4th and not 3th.

Comment: You can always add `ToList()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
List<OrderDateSummary> Result = OrderList       
    .Where(x => x.Date >= startDate && x.Date <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(z => new OrderDateSummary(){
          Date = z.Key, 
          Total = z.Count()
     }).OrderBy(d=> d.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Especially the use and non-use of `.Date` might be of interest. A user got the impression that one is missing. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/75156109/7733418

Answer (score 1):

Try code below which is linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication82
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<OrderDateSummary> orderSummary = null;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Parse("1/1/16"), 1.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("1/1/16"), 2.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, DateTime.Parse("1/2/16"), 3.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, DateTime.Parse("1/2/16"), 4.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, DateTime.Parse("1/2/16"), 5.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, DateTime.Parse("1/3/16"), 6.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, DateTime.Parse("1/3/16"), 7.00 });

            orderSummary = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("date"))
                .Select(x => new OrderDateSummary() { Date = x.Key, Total = x.Count() })
                .ToList();
        }

    }
    public class OrderDateSummary {
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public int Total { get; set; }
    }
}
```